# Dart Error Handling of specific error

Tags: dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

I would like to handle different errors that could happening in Dart.
I am using try/catch but wondering how to determine between the different errors that can occur.
For instance I have this error when there is no network connection:

```
PlatformException(Error 17020, FIRAuthErrorDomain, Network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.)
```

Whilst having this error when the username/password is incorrect:

```
PlatformException(Error 17009, FIRAuthErrorDomain, The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.)
```

I would like to take different actions depending on the error that occurs.
What would be the best approach here?
Update: Ended up using the below way!

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show PlatformException;

try {
      //Something!

    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      switch (e.code) {
        case "Error 17009":
          // handle
          break;
        case "Error 17020":
          // handle
          break;
        case "Error 17011":
          //handle
          break;
        default:
          throw new UnimplementedError(e.code);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Does this still work? I tried but my errors appear like this with no codes at all ```PlatformException(exception, The email address is already in use by another account., null)```

Comment: Hi. You are correct. This is no longer working! I am not able to catch the exception!

Comment: Seems there is now .code , .message  and .details which you can read out and handle as per exception.

Comment: I don't think `.code` exists anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a `try`/`catch` and a `switch`/`case`:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show PlatformException;


try {
  ...
} on PlatformException catch(e) {
  switch(e.code) {
    case '17009':
      // handle
      break;
    case '17020':
      // handle
      break;
    default:
      throw new UnimplementedError(error.code);
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to find out what value `e.code` is actually so that you can fix the `case: ...` statements

Comment: @LukeStanyer would you mind adding the link as comment instead of as content of my answer to keep it obvious who contributed what?