# Flutter: Unable to get error code from Firebase Authentication?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to use Google's Firebase Authentication in my flutter application. However, when handling user's login, I cannot seem to find a "code" to differentiate the types of exceptions for me to handle.

**Loginhandler.dart:**

```
class LoginHandler {
  String signup(_username, _password) async {
    bool _valid = false;
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: _username, password: _password)
          .catchError((e) {
            print(e);
            print(e.message);
            print(e.code);
            print(e.details);
          });
...
```

**Error outputs:**

```
W/BiChannelGoogleApi(26738): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@4e727e7
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26738): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
I/flutter (26738): PlatformException(exception, The email address is already in use by another account., null)
I/flutter (26738): The email address is already in use by another account.
I/flutter (26738): exception
I/flutter (26738): null

I/flutter (26738): PlatformException(exception, The given password is invalid. [ Password should be at least 6 characters ], null)
I/flutter (26738): The given password is invalid. [ Password should be at least 6 characters ]
I/flutter (26738): exception
I/flutter (26738): null
```

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746186/dart-error-handling-of-specific-error) Stack Overflow thread which highlights I can use a switch statement, but the above error output have no error "codes" for me to work with.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm able to access the "code" property of the error on Android.

```
      try {
          // login logic
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error: $e');
        setState(() {
          _isLoading = false;
          if (_isIos) {
            _errorMessage = e.details;
          } else
            _errorMessage = e.message;
          print(e.code); // can access the code here
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

This was a bug and it's already fixed with this PR https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/775.

---

<s>According to my experience, on iOS there's a bug and you can't get the error codes, only the error text messages. On Android, the error codes do work fine.</s>

On my apps I ended up checking for error text messages.

[The issue is already being tracked](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18312) on flutter, you can subscribe to it and get an update when its fixed.

By the way, [this is the pull request that fixes it](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/775), however it's not yet merged.